# Wrap text inside triangle SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, text, word-wrap

I have requirement to display data(TEXT) inside the triangle blocks.But that data(TEXT) should be wrapped inside the block of the triange. Please see the below image to understand clear.

The image shows that text data is displaying outside of the every block, that should be properly blended respective blocks of the triangle

[image: Click this link to see the image ,what image showing is , text data is displaying outside of the every block, that should be properly blended respective blocks of the triangle]

```
var svg = d3.select("#" + instanceData.id).insert("svg")
    .attr("id", instanceData.id + "svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .append("g");


var data = series0;
var pyramid = d3.pyramid()
    .size([w, h])
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.population;
    });

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate('linear-closed')
    .x(function(d, i) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d, i) {
        return d.y;
    });

var g = svg.selectAll(".pyramid-group")
    .data(pyramid(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "pyramid-group");

g.append("path").attr({
    "d": function(d) {

        return line(d.coordinates);

    },
    "fill": function(d) {
        /* console.log("test "+incr);
        if(incr==0){
        colorCode="rgb(255,0,0)";
        }else if(incr==1){
        colorCode="rgb(255,255,0)";
        }else if(incr==2){
        colorCode="rgb(0,128,0)";
        } */
        incr++;
        return color(d.region);

    }
});

g.append("text")
    .attr({
        "y": function(d, i) {
            if (d.coordinates.length === 4) {
                return (((d.coordinates[0].y - d.coordinates[1].y) / 2) + d.coordinates[1].y) + 5;
            } else {
                return (d.coordinates[0].y + d.coordinates[1].y) / 2 + 10;
            }
        },
        "x": function(d, i) {
            return w / 2;
        }
    })
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.region;
    });
```

Comment: and you want us to code this for you, right ? with no effort from your side ?

Comment: do u know i am not putting effort.I have wrote code to render image,my only concern is to display data inside the  block.

Comment: so put your code. We need to see code to know you have done an effort ;) and not simply put an image. How you think we can help with an image ?

Comment: I don't have good idea in CSS .So I posted here.please remove your negative vote.

Comment: `I have wrote code to render image` : show us your code. I am helping you improving your question unless you will get more downvotes then question will be closed

Comment: ok .I will post it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif please see the code.

Comment: better, but can you make it working ? i mean something that we can test directly on the site ... you may use snippet/codepen/jsfild ..etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah sure..

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is very difficult to complete it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<html> <meta charset="utf-8"> <script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script> <script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script> <style> svg { font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; height: 425px; margin: 25px; width: 900px; } .type { fill: #888; text-anchor: middle; } .shape { fill: #eee; stroke: #ccc; } </style> <svg> <!-- Text that will use the D3plus default wrapping. --> <text class="type" dy="15px" x="75px">Wrapped</text> <rect class="shape" height="150px" width="150px" y="50px"></rect> <text id="rectWrap" class="wrap" y="50px" font-size="12"> Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not. </text> <circle class="shape" r="75px" cx="75px" cy="300px"></circle> <text id="circleWrap" class="wrap" y="225px" x="0px" font-size="12"> Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not. </text> <!-- Text that D3plus will resize to fit the available space. --> <text class="type" dy="15px" x="275px">Resized</text> <rect class="shape" height="150px" width="150px" y="50px" x="200px"></rect> <text id="rectResize" class="wrap" y="50px" x="200px" font-size="12"> Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not. </text> <circle class="shape" r="75px" cx="275px" cy="300px"></circle> <text id="circleResize" class="wrap" y="225px" x="200px" font-size="12"> Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not. </text> <!-- For comparison, how SVG would display the text without D3plus. --> <text class="type" dy="15px" x="475px">Default Behavior</text> <rect class="shape" height="150px" width="150px" y="50px" x="400px"></rect> <text class="wrap" y="50px" x="400px" font-size="12"> Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not. </text> <circle class="shape" r="75px" cx="475px" cy="300px"></circle> <text class="wrap" y="225px" x="400px" font-size="12"> Here is a long text string that SVG should wrap by default, but it does not. </text> </svg> <script> // Wrap text in a rectangle. d3plus.textwrap() .container(d3.select("#rectWrap")) .draw(); // Wrap text in a rectangle, and size the text to fit. d3plus.textwrap() .container(d3.select("#rectResize")) .resize(true) .draw(); // Wrap text in a circle. d3plus.textwrap() .container(d3.select("#circleWrap")) .draw(); // Wrap text in a circle, and size the text to fit. d3plus.textwrap() .container(d3.select("#circleResize")) .resize(true) .draw(); </script>
```